# Хостинг видео. Прямая ссылка на видео

Tags: android, веб-программирование

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос с хостингом видео на стороннем ресурсе. Нужно выложить видео на сторонний сервис с возможностью получения прямой ссылки на файл. Нужно это для воспроизведения видео на Android через MediaPlayer. Попробовал несколько вариантов.
1) Положить видео на Youtube. У них неплохое sdk есть для воспроизведения видео с сайта. Но есть вероятность того, что доступ к файлам может быть закрыт из-за авторских прав.
2) Говорил со службой поддержки Вконтакте. У них есть возможность получить прямую ссылку на файл. Мне такую возможность не дали сказав что нет на то веских причин. И посоветовали пользоваться ссылкой на фрейм.
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал https://aws.amazon.com/ru/cloudfront/details/#faq

Comment: @Suvitruf . Спасибо. Я так понимаю бесплатного сыра я не найду:)